# Is there a method to convert PyUnicodeObject variable to PyObject type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A value which is a PyUnicodeObject need to be passed to PyObject variable.
Is there any conversion method for that?

thanks
karnol

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a cast in your C code for this purpose:

```
PyUnicodeObject *p = ...whatever...;
callsomefun((PyObject*)p);
```

All the various specific, concrete types `PyWhateverObject` can be thought of as being "derived from" PyObject.  Now C doesn't have the concept of inheritance so there's no "derived" in it, but the Python VM synthesizes it very simply, by ensuring every such object's first struct member (or first member's first member, or...) is a `PyObject` struct (there's a macro for that).  This guarantees that normal C casting of pointers (although technically "risky" as the compiler cannot check that correctness -- if you cast the wrong thing you'll just crash during runtime;-) works as intended when used correctly between a pointer to PyObject and any pointer to a specific, concrete Python type struct.

Comment: tel me for
PyUnicodeObject type -> PyBytesObject type


PyUnicodeObject *p = ...whatever...;

callafun((PyByteObject*)p);

Got a Bus Error.

Comment: @kamol, each of `PyUnicodeObject` and `PyBytesObject` is a _separate_ "conceptual subclass" of `PyObject`, so the cast would not work there (and that's **not** what you asked in your Q, so I suggest you edit it to cover your **real** question).  For your very specific and completely different current question, see http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/unicode.html#PyUnicode_Encode (and be sure to use a local variable for the byte object you thus create as you'll have to decref it after the call is done, unless what you're calling is a rare function that _steals_ a reference).

Answer (score 2):

`PyUnicodeObject` is a subset of `PyObject` so there shouldn't be any problem passing it.

Comment: ...except of course that the C compiler cannot possibly KNOW that (having no concept of subset, subclass, inheritance, etc) so you DO need a cast (pointer to pointer cast) as I explain in my answer.